# Way to use correctly patch.muliple

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I am new to mocking using patch.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple

And wondering why:

```
with patch.multiple(lock, cache=local_cache, LOCK_TIMEOUT=1):
```

is not equivalent to:

```
with patch.object(lock, 'cache', local_cache):
    with patch.object(lock, 'LOCK_TIMEOUT', 1):
```

How should one setup patch.multiple to get same effect?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of calling `patch.multiple` is:

```
with patch.multiple('utils.lock', cache=local_cache, LOCK_TIMEOUT=1):
```